# How to create a 3D surface in R?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, surface

I am trying to make a 3D surface plot in R. In this the values for the z and x axes should be within a given range, and the value of y should depend on both x and z as described in the function.

```
z <- maxGiraffeNumber <- c(100:2400)
x <- Tourism <- c(1:100)
y <- Rain <- 100/(17/((z/365)*0.3))*(100-y)
surface3d(x,y,z, col=colors)
```

running this code gives me the following error

> Error in rgl.surface(x = 1:100, y = 100:2400, z = c(14.7789550384904,  : 
>     'y' length != 'x' rows * 'z' cols

Thank you for your help

Comment: First, you have the definitions of `z` and `y` switched - I'll comment as if they were correct. You've calculated `z` values along a few lines, not a surface. You need to calculate `z` for every combination of `x` and `y`. Try `data = expand.grid(x, y)` to generate all combinations, then calculate `z` for all of those points.

Comment: Hello! You might try updating your question with a full, reproducible snippet of code.  Your use of `y` in the declaration of `y` obviously won't work, for example... and you might also want to add the `library()` that you're using that provides the `surface3d()` function.   In either case, assuming that it comes from the `rgl` package, you need to make sure that `x`, `y` have the same number of rows/columns as your `z` vector/matrix has values. Check out the example from the function documentation for clues.

Comment: (Also, `100:2400` is fairly big - `length(100:2400) * length(1*100)` is about 230,000 points. That's not so big as to really cause performance issues, but your graph would probably look just as nice if you used `seq(100, 2400, by = 5)` and only used 46,000 points. It's good to think about the lengths involved when you start generating all possible combinations of things.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is stated fairly well in the error. To produce a surface plot you need a vector of x co-ordinates of any length and a vector of y co-ordinates of any length. However, your z vector needs to have a value at every (x, y) co-ordinate, which means you need to be sure that `length(z) == length(x) * length(y)`. However, what you have is x of length 100, y of length 2301 and z of length 2301.

If you have a function you want to apply to every possible combination of x and y, you can use `outer`.

I'll give an example of producing a surface with something similar to the code you have created here, but it's probably not exactly what you were looking for, since it's not clear exactly what you are trying to do.

```
library(rgl)

f <- function(x, y) 100 / (17/((x / 365) * 0.3)) * (100 - y)
y <- Rain <- c(1:100)
x <- Tourism <- c(1:100)
z <- maxGiraffeNumber <- outer(Rain, Tourism, f)
surface3d(Tourism, Rain, maxGiraffeNumber, col = "red")
```

Which makes the following rotatable 3D surface pop-up:
[image]